# Disable ESLint in NextJS app, for a specific .json file

Tags: json, next.js, eslint

How can I disable ESlint for a specific .json file in nextjs app?
I've tried to create a file .eslintignore, to add in .eslintrc.json, in tsconfig.json and none of them seems to work. The error is:

```bash
./folder/jsonfile.json:1:2754821
Type error: Property value can only be string literal, numeric literal, 'true', 'false', 'null', object literal or array literal.
```

The json is in format:

```json
{"idlist":{"ids":[
{"id":1234,"name":"name here"},
{"id":234,"name":"name here"},
{"id":552,"name":"name here"}
```

and I import it inside a page, like this:

```js
import idlist from "@/folder/jsonfile.json"
```

Note that the file is pretty big (like 8MB of data).

edit, what I have tried:

.eslintignore with:

```
folder/*.json
folder/**.json
folder/
folder/jsonfile.json
/folder/
/folder/jsonfile.json
folder/*
folder/**
```

adding `/* eslint-ignore */` at the top of the json file

adding to package.json eslint like here https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/ignore